# pandas str.replace get nothing

Tags: python, regex

I run a program:

```
# encoding=utf-8
import pandas
df=pandas.DataFrame([['11-20','a',1],['10-20  更新于16-10-20 18:07','b',2],['15-12-27','c',3],['15-10-26  更新于10-26 23:52','d',4]],columns=['date','name','type'])
df.date=df.date.str.replace('^(\d+)(-)(\d+)((-)\d+){0,1}(.*)','\1\2\3\4')
print df
```

this is result:

```
    date name  type
0         a     1
1         b     2
2         c     3
3         d     4
```

I want to get the result:

```
       date name  type
0     11-20    a     1
1     10-20    b     2
2  15-12-27    c     3
3  15-10-26    d     4
```

I also check this regex on https://regex101.com/r/apIT0O/8. But I don't know where is the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make the replacement groups literal:

```
df.date.str.replace('^(\d+)(-)(\d+)((-)(\d+)){0,1}(.*)',r'\1\2\3\4')

#0       11-20
#1       10-20
#2    15-12-27
#3    15-10-26
#Name: date, dtype: object
```

Or you can use double backslash:

```
df.date.str.replace('^(\d+)(-)(\d+)((-)(\d+)){0,1}(.*)', '\\1\\2\\3\\4')
```

---

Without using regex, you can also split on a white space and take the first element:

```
df.date.str.split(" ").str[0]

#0       11-20
#1       10-20
#2    15-12-27
#3    15-10-26
#Name: date, dtype: object
```

Comment: Yes,it works. but the df.date.str.replace('^(\d+)(-)(\d+)((-)(\d+)){0,1}(.*)', '\\1\\2\\3\\4')  only works on python 3.+.Could you tell me the difference? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can simplify your regex.

```
df.date.str.replace('^(\d+-\d+)(-\d+)?.*',r'\1\2')
```

See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/apIT0O/9